# earliest start date for unique id

Tags: sas

ESN is an id column that has multiple observations per esn, so repeated values of esn occur.  For a given esn, I want to find the earliest service start date (and call it first), and I want to find the proper end date (called last) the if/then statement for how "last" is chosen  is correct, but I get the following errors when I run the code below:

```
340        first = min(of start(*));
               ---
               71
ERROR 71-185: The MIN function call does not have enough arguments.
```

here is the code I used

```
data three_1; /*first and last date created ?? used to ignore ? in data*/
set three;
format first  MMDDYY10. last  MMDDYY10.;
by esn;
array start(*)  service_start_date;
array stop(*) service_end_date entry_date_est ;
do i=1 to dim(start);
  first = min(of start(*));
end;
do i=1 to dim(stop);
  if esn_status = 'Cancelled' then last = min(input(service_end_date, MMDDYY10.), input(entry_date_est, MMDDYY10.));
  else last = max(input(service_end_date, MMDDYY10.), input(entry_date_est, MMDDYY10.));
end;
run;
```

"esn" "service_start_date"  "service_end_date" "entry_date_est"  "esn_status"

1 10/12/2010  01/01/2100  10/12/2012  cancelled

1 05/02/2009  02/12/2010  10/09/2012   cancelled

1 04/05/2011  03/04/2100 10/02/2012  cancelled

the results should be first= 05/02/2009 and last=10/12/2012

Comment: esn is in the format mmddyy10.

Comment: Are you trying to determine max and min dates *per row*, or *across rows*? Can you describe (or show) your input data a bit more?

Comment: a given esn may have multiple rows where dates service_start_date changes within that particular esn, thats why i used the min function. I'll edit the post with an example at the bottom.

Comment: ESN is actually a character variable since some values start with a letter.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and the min(), max(), etc. functions operate horizontally across rows of a data set, not vertically across multiple records.

Assuming esn_status is constant for a given esn, then you need to sort your input by esn and service_start_date.  You can use a data step to collect the values you want.

```
data three; /*thanks Joe for the data step to create the example data*/
length esn_status $10;
format service_start_date service_end_date entry_date_est MMDDYY10.;
input esn (service_start_date service_end_date entry_date_est) (:mmddyy10.) esn_status $;
datalines;
1 10/12/2010 01/01/2100 10/12/2012 cancelled
1 05/02/2009 02/12/2010 10/09/2012 cancelled
1 04/05/2011 03/04/2100 10/02/2012 cancelled
;;;;
run;

proc sort data=three;
by esn service_start_date;
run;

data three_1(keep=esn esn_status start last);
set three;
format start last date9.;
by esn;
retain start last;
if first.esn then do;
    start = service_start_date;
    last = service_end_date;
end;

if esn_status = "cancelled" then
    last = min(last,service_end_date,entry_date_est);
else
    last = max(last,service_end_date,entry_date_est);

if last.esn then
    output; 
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

A DoW loop will get to where you want, or you could do it in SQL.  Your desired results don't match with the actual results as far as I can tell, so you may need to make some adjustments.  You'd need a second WANT dataset for the non-cancelled folks, I don't think there's an easy way to put it in one data step.

```
data have;
length esn_status $10;
format service_start_date service_end_date entry_date_est MMDDYY10.;
input esn (service_start_date service_end_date entry_date_est) (:mmddyy10.) esn_status $;
datalines;
1 10/12/2010 01/01/2100 10/12/2012 cancelled
1 05/02/2009 02/12/2010 10/09/2012 cancelled
1 04/05/2011 03/04/2100 10/02/2012 cancelled
;;;;
run;
data want_cancelled;
first = 99999;
last = 99999;
do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.esn);
 set have(where=(esn_status='cancelled'));
 by esn;
 first = min(first,service_start_date);
 last = min(last,service_end_date,entry_date_est);
end;
output;
keep first last esn;
format first last mmddyy10.;
run;
```